# Media player not reading from socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, id3

Im attempting to write a song file through a socket and have the media player read from it, however the media player will crash on certain songs with a "Connection Reset by Peer" error.  When I remove the id3 information from these songs, the song will be able to stream fine and the media player will not crash.

The only difference in the songs that play and the ones that dont is that if there is a lot of id3 information (such as album art) then the song wont play.

Also, if I do not use the socket, but instead just have the media player read straight from a URL, the media player will work fine.

Comment: Could the issue be similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209382/streaming-with-android-mediaplayer-in-sdk-8/4574317#4574317

Comment: No, I'm actually making sure to use "\r\n" line endings and I am still having the same issue.